How can I access controls of form in another form
I'm working in a windows form application. I have two forms; in form A I have two picture box and in form B, I have a button. I want form B to show a message when I click on picturebox2 in form A and a button in form B. If I click on picturebox1 on form A and button on form B, then show no message.
My current code is -
Form A:
namespace message
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       
        public bool f ;
        public bool t ;
        
        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }


   private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        f = true;
        t = false;

    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        f = false;
        t = true; 

    }

Form B:
 namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 ff = new Form1();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (ff.t == true && ff.f == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sgfrdxgr");
            }
        
    
    }
}



I'm guessing Form1 ff = new Form1(); creates a 2nd Form1 but you need to use the originial.

1st: The two Boolean in Form1 (f and t) are not controls, they are just public fields. 2nd: Your code doesn't show any relationship between the two forms (nor does it show how the forms are created). Saying Form1 ff = new Form1(); will instanciate a Form1 object instance  but it will not cause it to be shown. If you are already showing a Form1, then the new instance will not be related to the already shown one

what should i do now? can you show me in code please

You can pass a parameter to the constructor of the second form as shown here

i can't understand the code can you explain
